# Javascript that reads in a url takes a certain div tag from the html page and place it in another page.

Tags: javascript, html

Hi I'm kind of new to this stuff, but I would like to be able to input a file path or url then the javascript will read a certain div tag then takes it from that html page and place it in another page which I can also input the url or file path. Is this possible? and can anyone put me on the right track?

Comment: I think you can do it only by opening a page by yourself from the page you want to use to do "the insert"

Answer (score 0):

Using [Jquery](http://jquery.com/) and [AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) you can specify a file path and read a certain div tag's HTML. I am not sure that you can place that html into a different page other than the one you are on.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'ajax/test.html',
    success: function(data) {
        $('.result').html($(data).find("#myDiv").html());
    }
});
```

Comment: How about if the javascript built a page its self and then placed the div tag from the other page into that is that possible?

Comment: You could try that. You can manipulate the body's HTML using jQuery as follows: $("body").html("<div>This is the new page</div>");

Comment: I should say that this will all done localy so there is no really problem with secruity or anything. I would be using this to test a certain div in other pages. So I'll give what you said a go and get back to you thanks for the help kleinkie :D